# searchable-dropdown-picker-in-react-native not able to Select?

Tags: react-native

I am using the `react-native-searchable-dropdown` to select an item from the dropdown. Selecting an item doesn't work, what could cause this?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import SearchableDropdown from 'react-native-searchable-dropdown';

const OrderSearchDropdown = () => {

    const [serverData, setServerData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://aboutreact.herokuapp.com/demosearchables.php')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                //Successful response from the API Call
                setServerData(responseJson.results);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
          
            <Fragment>
                <SearchableDropdown
                    onTextChange={(text) => alert(text)}
                    onItemSelect={(item) => alert(item)} 
                    items={serverData}                    
                    defaultIndex={2}                  
                    placeholder="Start type to search"                    
                    resetValue={false}                   
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"             
                />
            </Fragment>
            
        </>
    );
}

export default OrderSearchDropdown;
```

Comment: are the alerts fired?

Comment: onItemSelect alerts  not firing but onTextChange alert firing

Comment: When I am trying to select items from dropdown getting error like---
VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain SrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.